# Vim: insert empty line above current line (not open, i.e. without entering Insert mode)

Tags: vim

is there a way of inserting a new line above the current, without opening the line (so without entering Insert mode)? That is, like "O", but without opening.

Comment: What does "opening a line" mean?

Comment: "opening a line" means going form normal mode to insert mode, which is what happens when you press "O" (oh).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use Tim Pope's plugin [unimpared](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) which has a command specifically for this purpose:

`[<space>`

And if you want to add a space after the line you are on:

`]<space>`

Answer (score 37):

The definition of your request is `O`.

Logically when inserting a new line above would be `O`.

To insert before the curser: `i`
After: `a`
Before the line (home): `I`
Append at the end of line: `A`

The closest I think you'll come is `I` which will put the cursor at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The scenario is this: I'm in normal mode and want to insert a blank line above the one I'm currently on, while staying in normal mode. Pressing "O" puts me in insert mode. Maybe there's no way to do it and that's ok, just thought I would ask :)

Comment: Just map it, `m\`O+Esc\``

Comment: Good idea, hadn't considered that. Did a :noremap <leader>O O<ESC>

Comment: 2tmadsen: 
You can map this <yourkey> O<ESC>

Answer (score 10):

```
:h append()
```

It won't move the cursor, it will let you insert as many lines (empty or not) as you wish, and it won't modify the previous position mark.

```
call append(line('.')-1, '')
```

Comment: yah, that is +1 neat! /me changes his vimrc

Comment: Well, it got a few advantages when it comes to scripting. It's bit overkill to type otherwise.

Comment: +1 for a solution that works regardless of how one has set `formatoptions`

Answer (score 5):

You can map whatever key or key sequence you like to

```
m`O<ESC>``
```

this inserts a blank line above the current one keeping you in normal mode and without changing cursor position.

Comment: so the command to map this to Alt-O would be :map <M-o> m`O<ESC>``

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
:nmap <CR>_i<CR><ESC>
```